# PHP MySQL request from Objective-C iPhone app not POST-ing to my table

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c

I'm trying to make a simple app that POSTs data to a MySQL server (WAMP or MAMP) at my home, so that when we go to our robotics competition in St. Louis, we are able to add scouting data about teams to a database and pull from it later.

I'm having trouble getting the data to post to the table I have set up.

Here is the Objective C code:

```
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"teamNumber=%@&matchNumber=%@&autoGoal=%@&autoReachedOW=%@&autoCrossedDef=%@&teleopOffense=%@&teleopCrossedDef=%@&teleopHighGoalsMissed=%@&teleopHighGoalsMade=%@&teleopLowGoalsMissed=%@&teleopLowGoalsMade=%@&teleopEndGame=%@&teleopDefense=%@&teleopShotsDef=%@&teleopShotsDisrupted=%@&teleopPenalties=%@",
                    teamNumber,
                    matchNumber,
                    autoGoal,
                    autoReachedOW,
                    autoCrossedDef,
                    teleopOffense,
                    teleopCrossedDef,
                    teleopHighGoalsMissed,
                    teleopHighGoalsMade,
                    teleopLowGoalsMissed,
                    teleopLowGoalsMade,
                    teleopEndGame,
                    teleopDefense,
                    teleopShotsDef,
                    teleopShotsDisrupted,
                    teleopPenalties];

NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost:8888/add.php"]];
// set Request Type
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
// Set content-type
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
// Set Request Body
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
// Now send a request and get Response
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
// Log Response
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
```

Here is the PHP code that I am using to make the request from the iPhone app:

```
<?php

    $servername = “localhost:8888”;
    $username = “root”;
    $password = “root”;
    $dbname = “teamdata”;

    $db_conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        echo "Connection Failed.";
    }

    $teamNumber = ($_POST['teamNumber']);
    $matchNumber = ($_POST['matchNumber']);
    $autoGoal = ($_POST['autoGoal']);
    $autoReachedOW = ($_POST['autoReachedOW']);
    $autoCrossedDef = ($_POST['autoCrossedDef']);
    $teleopOffense = ($_POST['teleopOffense']);
    $teleopCrossedDef = ($_POST['teleopCrossedDef']);
    $teleopHighGoalsMissed = ($_POST['teleopHighGoalsMissed']);
    $teleopHighGoalsMade = ($_POST['teleopHighGoalsMade']);
    $teleopLowGoalsMissed = ($_POST['teleopLowGoalsMissed']);
    $teleopLowGoalsMade = ($_POST['teleopLowGoalsMade']);
    $teleopEndGame = ($_POST['teleopEndGame']);
    $teleopDefense = ($_POST['teleopDefense']);
    $teleopShotsDef = ($_POST['teleopShotsDef']);
    $teleopShotsDisrupted = ($_POST['teleopShotsDisrupted']);
    $teleopPenalties = ($_POST['teleopPenalties']);

    $qry = 'INSERT INTO appdata (`teamNumber`,`matchNumber`,`autoGoal`,`autoReachedOW`,`autoCrossedDef`,`teleopOffense`,`teleopCrossedDef`, `teleopHighGoalsMissed`, `teleopHighGoalsMade`, `teleopLowGoalsMissed`, `teleopLowGoalsMade`, `teleopEndGame`, `teleopDefense`, `teleopShotsDef`, `teleopShotsDisrupted`, `teleopPenalties`) VALUES ($teamNumber,$matchNumber,$autoGoal,$autoReachedOW,$autoCrossedDef,$teleopOffense,$teleopCrossedDef,$teleopHighGoalsMissed,$teleopHighGoalsMade,$teleopLowGoalsMissed,$teleopLowGoalsMade,$teleopEndGame,$teleopDefense,$teleopShotsDef,$teleopShotsDisrupted,$teleopPenalties)';

    if ($qry) { $message = "success"; }
    else { $message = "failed"; }

    echo utf8_encode($message);
?>
```

When I run the app and press the save button (which runs the Objective C code), I don't get any rows added to my table on my local server.

I am not getting any NSLog outputs.

If someone could point me in the right direction, please do so. If you need more info, let me know. I will be monitoring this for a few hours. Thank you.

Comment: I didnt go through each line of your code, but just noticed that you are creating a `$qry` variable but not using it any where. You would need to use your connection variable and insert it into DB. Probably something like `$db_conn->query($qry)`

Comment: @GoodSp33d I tried this, and it still isn't working.

Comment: Can you turn on errors for PHP and see if anything is wrong in PHP ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d How do I do that?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could try:

First, check the logs on your web server. This should give you the status code of any requests that are going through.

Second, when you're running `sendSynchronousRequest`, you should be setting the values of the `returningResponse` and `error` variables. Those will give you a great deal of information about the request that just ran.

As you're running the request synchronously (not best practice by the way), you'll be able to set a breakpoint on the line of code after this one and inspect the contents of those two variables.

`sendSynchronousRequest` won't spit out anything to the console by default, so you have to do that manually.